# Java NIO still blocking GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, nio

Edit: GUI now pops up(thanks to matt ), but when I press the start button, the program completely freezes and I have to end it in jGrasp.

I have an issue with java NIO where my GUI doesn't pop-up when I run the server code.

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Server extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

  JButton start = null;

  public Server(){
     JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
     start = new JButton("Start");
     add(panel);
     panel.add(start);
     start.addActionListener(this);
  }

  public void start(){
     try{
        Selector selector = Selector.open();

        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 0);
        serverChannel.bind(hostAddress);

        serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        while (true) {
           int readyCount = selector.select();
           if (readyCount == 0) {
              continue;
           }
        // process selected keys...
           Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
           Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
           while (iterator.hasNext()) {
              SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
           // Remove key from set so we don't process it twice
              iterator.remove();
           // operate on the channel...
           // client requires a connection
              if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                 ServerSocketChannel server = (ServerSocketChannel)  key.channel();    
              // get client socket channel
                 SocketChannel client = server.accept();
              // Non Blocking I/O
                 client.configureBlocking(false);
              // record it for read/write operations (Here we have used it for read)
                 client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                 continue;
              }
           }
        }
     }
     catch(IOException ioe){}
  }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
     if(e.getSource()==start){
        start();
     }
  }

  public static void main(String []args){
     Server gui = new Server();
     gui.setTitle("Server");
     gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     gui.pack();
     gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     gui.setResizable(false);
     gui.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?
I followed [this](https://medium.com/coderscorner/tale-of-client-server-and-socket-a6ef54a74763) tutorial and after simple debugging(`Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = readyKeys.iterator();` was missing the `<SelectionKey>` part), I compiledit, ran, and...nothing.
This is the entire code that I wrote and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It is not good to start a never ending loop in your constructor.

Comment: @matt I'll move it into a method then, and report back. Thank you.

Comment: @matt I changed ``` public Server(){...}``` to ```public void start{...} ```, and added an actionListener, but now the entire program stops working(or get's blocked I guess?).
edit: I will edit the post now to reflect the change in code

Comment: Did you check the answers posted? You'll need to separate your tasks. Once you've done that, I suspect you're going to want to run `runServer` from an action listener, which is fine you just need another thread to run the server.

Comment: I did, works  flawlessly!

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to use a new thread. Note though, your question is beginning to morph into a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate your tasks. One is to start a gui, and the other one is to start a server.

Make one task the server.

```
public void runServer() throws Exception{
        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);

        InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 0);
        serverChannel.bind(hostAddress);

        serverChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);

        while (true) {
           int readyCount = selector.select();
           if (readyCount == 0) {
              continue;
           }
           Set<SelectionKey> readyKeys = selector.selectedKeys();
           Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = readyKeys.iterator();
           while (iterator.hasNext()) {
              SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
              iterator.remove();
              if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                 ServerSocketChannel server = (ServerSocketChannel)  key.channel();    
              // get client socket channel
                 SocketChannel client = server.accept();
              // Non Blocking I/O
                 client.configureBlocking(false);
              // record it for read/write operations (Here we have used it for read)
                 client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                 continue;
              }
           }
        }
     }

}
```

Then make the other task the gui.

```
public void startGui(){
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    add(panel);
    panel.add(start);
    setTitle("Server");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Now your main method can be reduced to.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Server server = new Server();
    EventQueue.invokeAndWait( server::startGui );
    server.runServer();
}
```

This way, the gui is started on the EDT, and the server loop which never finishes takes up the main thread. Another small change. Don't extend JFrame, just create a JFrame in the startGui method. That way **all** gui work is done on the EDT.

Not that I have also removed your Exception handling and just made the methods throw Exception. That way you'll see a StackTrace.

In regards to your newer question, why is the gui freezing. It's because your blocking on the EDT. Your `start()` method never exits. The most crude method to fix this is to.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
 if(e.getSource()==start){
      new Thread( ()->start();).start();
 }
```

}

What that will do, is start a new thread to run your server. Notice the most obvious problem, if you click start more than once, it start more than one thread!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, using non-blocking I/O is probably not necessary. Instead, the main thread could continue to perform I/O (using traditional blocking calls), while scheduling updates to the UI with `SwingWorker`. These updates will occur in the Swing Event Dispatch Thread, so you don't even need to worry about creating your own threads.

Non-blocking IO allows you to check whether channels are ready to perform certain operations without blocking. If no I/O operations are ready, the thread can perform other tasks and check back later.

But in your program, you've written code that effectively waits (in a "busy-loop") until the operations are ready. Because the constructor never returns, the call to `setVisible()` is never even invoked. You never give the thread a chance to do any other work, including painting the UI.

Further, with Java Swing, there is a special thread that performs all updates to the UI. When you create components or update what they display, that work has to be done with that thread. Swing provides the [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class to schedule short tasks that manipulate the UI. You can learn more about concurrency in Swing by completing [the *Concurrency in Swing* tutorial.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: So I need to create a separate thread that handles the server processes, and separate the GUI from the server thread?

Comment: @PetarZanetic Yes. The server thread (main) should send tasks to Swing's Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) to be executed using `SwingWorker`.